# Access document in ASP.NET code behind?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

If I do this in javascript

```
document.attributes["Test"] ='1';
```

How can I access that in ASP.NET server side code?

I looked for `Attributes` on `this.Page`, but it wasn't there.

Comment: are you trying to acces form fields on the code-behind? like input element values?

Comment: what is `attributes`?

Comment: Well, they do exists according to http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp, but it warns you not to use them...

Answer (score 3):

Document attributes aren't posted back to the server.

What I do is add a hidden server control, then update that hidden control in javascript.  That will be posted back to the server, and can be accessed.

This would be the server control. (note the clientidmode attribute, this is so that I can easily access this control in javascript)

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="hdnTest"/>
```

Then in javascript

```
document.getElementById("hdnTest").value = '1';
```

And to access it in the codebehind

```
hdnTest.Value
```